# Owl Carousel plugin - want first selection to not be display all

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I am using the owl carousel plugin and I have a large number of photos in it. The default view shows all images and then allows the user to select sub categories. In order to keep the user from having to scroll past all of these I am looking to have the first sub grouping of images be the first thing the user is presented with rather than all the images.

```
                <ul class="container-filter categories-filter">
                    <li><a class="categories" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
                    <li><a class="categories active" data-filter=".one">Correctional</a></li>
                    <li><a class="categories" data-filter=".two">Animal Care</a></li>
                    <li><a class="categories" data-filter=".three">Restaurants</a></li>
                    <li><a class="categories" data-filter=".four">Industrial</a></li>
                    <li><a class="categories" data-filter=".five">Research</a></li>
                    <li><a class="categories" data-filter=".six">Healthcare</a></li>
                </ul>


            <div class="row container-grid nf-col-3">

                <div class="nf-item one spacing">
                    <div class="item-box">
                        <a class="cbox-gallary1" href="img/projectImages/corrections/1.jpg" title="Consequat massa quis">
                            <img alt="1" src="img/projectImages/corrections/1.jpg" class="item-container">
                            <div class="item-mask">
                                <div class="item-caption">
                                    <h5 class="white">Header</h5>
                                    <p class="white">Title</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div
```

Comment: First, you should ask some code to let us help you. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: My apologies, first time question. I've added the code now.